# Firefox and Thuderbird freezes OS after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 22.04, freeze, thunderbird

Firefox and Thunderbird freezes OS after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04. Both apps run for about 5 seconds before freezing the system. I tried changing snap Firefox to non-snap Firefox (deb) using instructions from https://www.makeuseof.com/things-to-do-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-2204-lts/ number 5, but system still freezes after running Firefox. System has stock software except for Chrome. Chrome works as expected as does the stock software. Upgrade removed nvidia driver.

Thank you, Tom

Comment: There might me remnants of the nvidia driver (that fools FF), see if you can remove / uninstall those; e.g. open a terminal and type `dpkg --list | grep -E '^ii.*nvidia*'` to see actually installed packages that may need to be removed before an attempt to reinstall the driver. (`sudo apt purge ...` where ... is a few [at a time] of the names in the second column)

Comment: I purged the packages but system still freezes when running firefox or thunderbird.

Comment: Packages that were purged were nvidia-340, nvidia-settings, screen-resolution-extra

Comment: So... `attempt to reinstall the driver.` 340 is a very old driver version, you should see several newer than so -> hit `Super` (Win key) and then type `Soft`... where you should see a reddish icon for 'Software & Updates' - click on it. Find the `Additional Drivers` tab; there should be a selection of several nVidia driver versions; unless it differs greatly from 20.04 *(which is what I am running; I see 7 different packages; v418 to 515)*. You may now attempt to run (activate) any of these.

Comment: There is nothing listed for video drivers in the Addtional Drivers tab. This was before I purged the three packages - nvidia-340, nvidia-settings, screen-resolution-extra, as well. In 20.04 it had two video drivers, an Ubuntu generic xorg video driver and the nvidia video driver. The video card is Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT.

Comment: Well, in that case I've got to suggest you find a driver that does support your hardware. I was not running Linux so far back, cannot advice where to go other than to nVidia looking for older drivers. Might be that the older(?) proprietary ones are the only(?) option.

Comment: What I do not understand is why using the internal ubuntu video driver and not using a specific video driver for the video card causes the system to hang when just using firefox or thunderbird. I should of kept using 20.04 instead of 22.04 if this was going to happen.

Comment: Hmm... tip: Google how to switch from Wayland to Xorg - you might get lucky. With Xorg, might be you can bring back nvidia driver in some form too.

Comment: No additional drivers using "Ubuntu on Xorg".How do you execute a .run file, specifically the Nvidia driver called NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.108.run file? When I double click on the file it loads a script for gedit (took a long time) for editing. I enabled the file's permissions to 'Allow execute file as program'.

Comment: Google "recovery mode", but first make sure you know where to find the *.run file as root. Then type `bash runfile-name.run` at the bash prompt in recovery mode. The run file needs to be run recovery mode as e.g. that is when no other drivers are "busy". . . . . . `bash runfile-name.run --help | less` tells what you can do with it.

Comment: note: My experience with *.run -version of the nVidia driver(s) is that they often dropped out (got disabled) by kernel and xorg updates; in that case I redid the install; run `... --uninstall` then immediately a reinstall (without "--uninstall") in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at an answer:

To have the update process cover all possible situations gracefully it would need a tremendous amount of work; install numerous major packages that could possibly be installed - on top of the basic, just installed Ubuntu version. Then do at least one test-run, do the update, see if anything broke (note: FIND that broken thing!), adjust for it, do another test run.

So, how much of this is done?
Personally I do not know, I wonder if anything at all.
Therefore I **assume** that - anything the admin/user of a system has installed on top of Ubuntu - *MAY* get affected *negatively* of an OS upgrade.

One such software package might be an older driver, e.g. older versions of the nvidia display driver.
... and this especially if the *.run version (provided by nVidia themselves) was used.

There is one more possible source of problems; the old driver might not work well with Wayland (which appeared as the default in 22.04). Switching to use Xorg *might* remedy this.

But then, with old hardware, the nVidia proprietary *.run file installer might be the only available option; especially if `Additional Drivers` (hit Win key, begin to type that) doesn't show anything useful.

To install such a file,

- make sure it is easy to find when logged in as root,
- boot into "recovery mode" (google it),
- do `fsck` (makes the fs writable), and `enable network` (needed?),
  *(=> allow 'normal' work, detect attempt to fix hindrances)*
- find the "root shell" option,
- uninstall any remnants of earlier / other related drivers,
- then do `bash driver-file-name.run --help | less` to see available options
- normally installation is just `bash driver-file-name.run` and
- `bash driver-file-name.run --uninstall` for removal of the driver.

Afterwards, while in use, e.g. kernel and xorg or wayland updates might disable the driver (e.g. overwriting settings), at such an occasion - uninstall then an immediate install (e.g. in recovery mode) - may well restore functionality.

Comment: This all sounds a bit too risky and complicated. I will decide what to do. Obviously Canonical either designed the upgrade so that old nvidia drivers would not work (why they removed the video drivers during the upgrade) or that they did not want to bother testing old video drivers. Why everything works except for Firefox and Thunderbird is a mystery.

Comment: I'd believe it rather is nVidia that has removed support for older hardware. And... the above is easier than it looks; mainly make disks writable, enable networking (if you need it) then drop into root shell and execute the the driver install, then reboot. Many times the description is "more complicated" than the actual "do it".

Comment: All the above has been about the nvidia drivers. `Why everything works except for Firefox and Thunderbird is a mystery.` - as I suggested above, google how to swap from Wayland to Xorg - the use of Wayland as default might be the actual cause for these to fail. Maybe also affecting the nvidia driver?! As it is old, Wayland might be a problem as it probably didn't "exist" as it was created.

Comment: I tried all three  - Unity, Ubuntu on XORG, and Ubuntu (wayland). "There is nothing listed for video drivers in the Addtional Drivers tab" as stated on Oct 6 20:13

Comment: "The above is easier than it looks; mainly make disks writable, enable networking (if you need it) then drop into root shell and execute the the driver install, then reboot. " I have never done anything like that before.

Comment: And who is to say that it is a video driver issue causing firefox and thunderbird to cause the OS to crash.

Comment: And if you believe that it is Nvidia that removed support then I guess that .run file won't work since a video driver was not included in the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having constant problems with Firefox since it went snap.

All I did to fix it was save all the settings from the current snap version, install 111.0.1 from Morzilla and use that instead. Should I need to revert or look something up the snap version is still usable. No crashes/freezes now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).